# Bizarre Child Menu Issue on WP Site

Tags: functions, menus, navigation

I have a bizarre problem that I just can't figure out.  I have been fixing this site for almost 3 days with so many customizations that the previous developer did.  The structure of this site was total chaos!

However, this menu/child menu bug has me stumped.  It will ONLY show the menu for Programs.  But if I delete the Programs menu, none of the other submenu's show up.  In fact, GET INVOLVED menu has several child sub menu's and they are not showing up.  Only Programs is able to display child menu's which makes no sense.
This is the URL:
https://thewomenscentreofhalton.com/

I have reviewed the functions.php file and I must be blind, because I can't see the problem.

Below is an excerpt that pertains to the menu from functions.php

```php
class main_nav extends Walker {

  var $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );

  function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul>\n";
  }

  function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
  }

  function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
    $class_names = $value = '';
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

    /* Add active class */
    if(in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
      $classes[] = 'active';
      unset($classes['current-menu-item']);
    }

    /* Check for children */
    $children = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'nopaging' => true, 'numberposts' => 1, 'meta_key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'meta_value' => $item->ID));
    if (!empty($children)) {
      $classes[] = 'has-sub';
    }

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li ' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</span></a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
  }

  function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= "</li>\n";
  }
}
```

---

Here is the code where it is used:

```php
 <div class="mid-header"> <div class="l_container clearfix"> <nav class="header-menu clearfix"> <div class="navToggle"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span></div> <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' , 'walker' => new main_nav() ) ); ?> </nav> </div> </div>
```

Comment: I notice your walker class extends from `Walker`, not `Walker_Nav_Menu`, is there a reason for this? You also haven't shared the code that uses this class

Comment: I don't really know... curious...

Comment: You should change it! Also it would be super helpful to see where `main_nav` is being used to create the nav menu output

Comment: @TomJNowell... How should I change it?  I don't mind changing the code... hahaha!

Comment: @TomJNowell do you mean you want to see the page template that uses it?

Comment: I am happy to share just about anything you need to help me help this client out.

Comment: Your `main_nav` gets used somewhere, seeing where it gets used would be helpful. Particularly the `wp_nav_menu` function call that uses it

Comment: and to change it so it extends `Walker_Nav_Menu` instead of `Walker`, go to `extends Walker` on the first line and change `Walker` to `Walker_Nav_Menu`

Comment: can you edit that into your question? Comments don't work for multiline code blocks. What kind of things are supposed to be in the other sub-menus? I'm not seeing much in this nav walker class that would be useful, have you tried just not using it?

Comment: You are right!  Sorry!  So I have added it to the bottom of the above code at the bottom.

Comment: Get Involved has 4 other menu items in it.  You can see it in the HTML of the page as a li item... but for whatever reason, the drop down just doesnt work.  So bizarre.

Comment: Oooooh, I see now. This has nothing to do with the PHP, the nav walker class and the code in your question are completely irrelevant and have no connection to your problem. Your sub-menus do exist, but there is no CSS code to un-hide them on hover. Thee Get involved menu works because someone wrote some javascript to unhide the sub-menu. This can be solved by looking up basic CSS dropdown menu styling. You need to set `display: block` when hovering on the parent item. The solution has nothing to do with WordPress

Comment: But if its CSS, why does that work on the Programs Menu but not on the Get Involved Menu?  I am SOOOOOOO UNBELIEVABLY grateful to you so far Tom... thank you for spending any time on this at all.

Comment: OMG... I think I just found the javascript you are talking about!  There is a js file called main.js... it has 16 lines of code on it.

I am going to insert a custom line for 2467 which is the Get Involved Menu. If it works, I will jump out of my chair.  Stand by.

$("#menu-item-47").hover(function() {$menu-item047 ul").slideToggle(1);

Comment: I just tried adding the display block, added entries to the js file to add menu-item-2469... no change... i flushed the server to see if maybe it was caching,... nothing,..

Comment: You should use CSS instead off hardcoding individual menus, see https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp, most themes bundle the same CSS for this, you should copy them, javascript is unnecessary

Comment: And you can tell that since the previous dev did `"#menu-item-47"` for the script selector that the code only targets that one menu item.  Not really that efficient or clever.